# Adding a jdbc driver to pentaho design studio and configuring the datasource

Tags: jdbc, driver, pentaho

I've just integrated pentaho's design studio into the BI server. Does anyone know how to add mysql jdbc drivers. I need to connect in order to define the relational action process.
In my research I found:

http://wiki.bizcubed.com.au/xwiki/bin/view/Pentaho%20Tutorial/Install%20Pentaho%20Design%20Studio#Comments

which specifies selecting
JDBC Driver, Edit, Extra Class Path from Preferences but no such preference exists,

http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?85148-Design-Studio-xaction-database-connection-dropdown-list-empty&highlight=add+jdbc+driver+to+design+studio

which resulted in me creating a jdbc folder in which I placed the drivers in `plugins\org.pentaho.designstudio.editors.actionsequence_4.0.0.stable\lib\`
but just as the author of the thread I'm stuck

http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?53303-Create-a-new-datasource&highlight=add+jdbc+driver+to+design+studio

suggests that:
3. If you are using the Pentaho DesignStudio you have to copy your jdbc (JAR files) to the plugins directory (in pentaho plugin) so you can develop, deploy and run your applications. This apply also to eclipse plugin (If you have now an Eclipse).
Which resulted in me placing the jar files in the plugin directory to no avail.

http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?53715-Can-t-add-new-datasource-GA-version&highlight=add+jdbc+driver+to+design+studio
    talks of a directory, rdw which does not exist

Any form of assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to configure the datasource by adding a Relational Process Action to your .xaction in the Pentaho Design Studio wherein you can specify the JDBC Driver, Username, Password and the Database URL. But first you have to put your MySQL JAR file in your lib folder `/path/to/biserver-ce/tomcat/lib`

You will also have to save your `*.xaction` file/s in the pentaho-solutions folder `/path/to/biserver-ce/pentaho-solutions` in order for your `*.xaction` files to connect to the database which you have assigned in your Relational Process Action.

Comment: Thanks cyril. I did all that, exactly as you suggested, prior to posting the question and things still do not work out.

Comment: @user1210959 Hmm, have you also tried to place the jars inside [/path/to/biserver-ce-3.8.0-stable/administration-console/jdbc] ?

Comment: @user1210959 And also have you configured the datasource through the dashboard (Pentaho User Console)? AFAIK the drivers just need to go to the tomcat/lib directory, because when you run the .xaction file, it goes through the BI Server, therefore using libraries and configured datasources in the BI Server.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem and solved as follow

1. place `mysql-connector-java-5.1.17.jar` under `(bi server path)\tomcat\lib\` folder
2. start Pentaho Admin Console (PAC) `http://127.0.0.1:8099` with

   ```
   user: admin
   password: password
   ```

   and add a connection there
3. use the name of the connection just created for action sequence as JNDI

The problem solved for me.