# JDBC Driver with PostgreSQL and Pentaho

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, pentaho

**Situation:**

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.1 and now I'm using Pentaho Report Designer to create reports from a data warehouse stored on a database. This database is named `bd-datawarehouse`.

The problem I have is when I try to create a connection from the Pentaho Report Designer to `bd-datawarehouse` database. I've configured all the settings and everything seems correct, like the next image:

[image]

**but when I click the `Test` button, it gives me the next error:**

```
Error connecting to database [conexion-dw-reporting] : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error occured while trying to connect to the database

Exception while loading class
org.postgresql.Driver


org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error occured while trying to connect to the database

Exception while loading class
org.postgresql.Driver


    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.normalConnect(Database.java:366)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:315)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:277)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:267)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.DatabaseFactory.getConnectionTestReport(DatabaseFactory.java:86)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.DatabaseMeta.testConnection(DatabaseMeta.java:2464)
    at org.pentaho.ui.database.event.DataHandler.testDatabaseConnection(DataHandler.java:533)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor133.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulDomContainer.invoke(AbstractXulDomContainer.java:329)
    at org.pentaho.ui.xul.swing.tags.SwingButton$OnClickRunnable.run(SwingButton.java:58)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.show(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Unknown Source)
    at org.pentaho.ui.xul.swing.tags.SwingDialog.show(SwingDialog.java:234)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.ui.datasources.jdbc.ui.XulDatabaseDialog.open(XulDatabaseDialog.java:256)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.ui.datasources.jdbc.ui.ConnectionPanel$EditDataSourceAction.actionPerformed(ConnectionPanel.java:159)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.show(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Unknown Source)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.designtime.swing.CommonDialog.performEdit(CommonDialog.java:156)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.ui.datasources.jdbc.ui.JdbcDataSourceDialog.performConfiguration(JdbcDataSourceDialog.java:759)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.ui.datasources.jdbc.JdbcDataSourcePlugin.performEdit(JdbcDataSourcePlugin.java:67)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.designer.core.actions.elements.EditDataSourceAction.performEdit(EditDataSourceAction.java:139)
    at org.pentaho.reporting.designer.core.actions.elements.EditDataSourceAction.actionPerformed(EditDataSourceAction.java:109)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Exception while loading class
org.postgresql.Driver

    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connectUsingClass(Database.java:421)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.normalConnect(Database.java:350)
    ... 121 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connectUsingClass(Database.java:412)
    ... 122 more

Hostname       : localhost
Port           : 5432
Database name  : bd-datawarehouse
```

You must know that all fields of settings are right (database name, port number, host name, user name and password).

Seeing the error, I've thought that the problem could be that I haven't the jdbc driver to connect a PostgreSQL database, so I've looked for it and I've done like the accepted answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9537273/adding-a-jdbc-driver-to-pentaho-design-studio-and-configuring-the-datasource) said: I've downloaded the driver for my postgresql 9.2 from [here](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html#supported) and I've put it on `...\biserver-ce\tomcat\lib\`, but the problem persists.

I don't know how to solve it, because I don't understand so deeply which is the problem.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The excepion `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` clearly indicates you put the jar file into the wrong directory. Your screenshot seems to be from a Swing GUI, whereas you state that you put the driver into a Tomcat directory. I doubt the Swing GUI uses the libraries from your Tomcat installation.

Comment: MASTER! I was putting the driver inside the wrong folder. I only just moved it to the right folder and it solves my problem. Please put your comment as answer, I want to appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

report-designer\lib\jdbc\
or 
bd-datawarehouse\lib\jdbc\

You need to place the appropriate jdbc jar file to above path. then you need to restart the pentaho reporting tool. It might be work. Its working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've downloaded the last version of the PostgreSQL JDBC 4.2 Driver and input it on the lib folder of the Database connection program, it worked for me  :)

https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html#supported